# CAEAGLLayer clear texture

Tags: ios, opengl-es

**How do you clear the rendered texture?**

I'm kind of lost in this OpenGL code I inherited from someone.  I've tried this, however it has no effect on it:

```
- (void)clearFrameBuffer {
    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

---

This is how the frame and render buffers are created:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);

//Onscreen framebuffer object
glGenFramebuffers(1, &_viewFramebufferIndex);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, self.viewFramebufferIndex);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_viewRenderbufferIndex);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, self.viewRenderbufferIndex);

[self.renderContext renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER
                           fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer];
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, self.viewRenderbufferIndex);
```

And this is how something is drawn (No, I don't fully understand this code):

```
- (void)drawSample:(CMSampleBufferRef)sample
{
    if (!sample) {
        return;
    }

    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sample);
    if (!pixelBuffer) {
        //There's something wrong with the frame, needs further debugging
        return;
    }

    if (![[EAGLContext currentContext] isEqual:self.renderContext]) {
        [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.renderContext];
    }

    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -kRenderSize * 0.5f, -kRenderSize * 0.5f,
        kRenderSize * 0.5f, -kRenderSize * 0.5f,
        -kRenderSize * 0.5f, kRenderSize * 0.5f,
        kRenderSize * 0.5f, kRenderSize * 0.5f
    };

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, self.viewFramebufferIndex);

    // Set the view port to the entire view
    glViewport(0,
               0,
               CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) * self.contentScaleFactor,
               CGRectGetHeight(self.frame) * self.contentScaleFactor);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, self.viewRenderbufferIndex);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(textureParams[kOffsetProgramBorder]);
    // Draw the layer rectangle
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, vertices);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_POSITION);
    glUniform4f(textureParams[kOffsetUniformBorder_0], 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    if (!textureCache) {
        CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                     NULL,
                                     self.renderContext,
                                     NULL,
                                     &textureCache);
    }

    OSType framePixelFormat = CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(pixelBuffer);
    size_t frameWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
    size_t frameHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);
    size_t stopDraw = 0;
    CVReturn error[3];
    CVOpenGLESTextureRef texturePlane[3];
    GLfloat textureWidth;

    if (CVPixelBufferIsPlanar(pixelBuffer)) {
        // adjust for YUVB
        textureWidth = (GLfloat)frameWidth/(GLfloat)CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0);
    }
    else {
        // adjust for RGBA
        textureWidth = (GLfloat)frameWidth/(GLfloat)(CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer)>>2);
    }

    // prepare vertex arrays for rendering
    GLfloat textureVertices[] = {
        0.0f,          1.0f,
        textureWidth,  1.0f,
        0.0f,          0.0f,
        textureWidth,  0.0f,
    };
    CGRect viewRect = [self viewSamplingRectFromTexture:CGSizeMake(frameWidth, frameHeight)];
    GLfloat viewVertices[] = {
        viewRect.origin.x,                     viewRect.origin.y,
        viewRect.origin.x+viewRect.size.width, viewRect.origin.y,
        viewRect.origin.x,                     viewRect.origin.y+viewRect.size.height,
        viewRect.origin.x+viewRect.size.width, viewRect.origin.y+viewRect.size.height,
    };

    // different handling for each format


   // Use shader program.

    glUseProgram(textureParams[kOffsetProgramYUVB]);
    //Mapping the luma plane of a 420v buffer as a source texture:
    error[0] = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                            textureCache,
                                                            pixelBuffer,
                                                            NULL,
                                                            GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                            GL_LUMINANCE,
                                                            CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0),
                                                            CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0),
                                                            GL_LUMINANCE,
                                                            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                                            0,
                                                            &texturePlane[0]);
    if (error[0] == kCVReturnSuccess) {
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(texturePlane[0]));
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glUniform1i(textureParams[kOffsetUniformYUVB_0], 0);
    }
    else
        stopDraw++;
    //Mapping the chroma plane of a 420v buffer as a source texture:
    error[1] = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                            textureCache,
                                                            pixelBuffer,
                                                            NULL,
                                                            GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                            GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA,
                                                            CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1),
                                                            CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1),
                                                            GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA,
                                                            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                                            1,
                                                            &texturePlane[1]);
    if (error[1] == kCVReturnSuccess) {
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(texturePlane[1]));
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glUniform1i(textureParams[kOffsetUniformYUVB_1], 1);
    }
    else
        stopDraw++;
    if (!stopDraw) {
        // Draw the texture on the screen with OpenGL ES 2
        glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, viewVertices);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_POSITION);
        glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_TEXCOORD, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, textureVertices);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_TEXCOORD);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    }
    [self.renderContext presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
    for (size_t i=0; i<2; i++)
        if (error[i] == kCVReturnSuccess) {
            glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(texturePlane[i]), 0);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
            CFRelease(texturePlane[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Fist of all: It's not a texture, it is a renderbuffer. What do you want to achieve? Btw. you are never calling your `clearFrameBuffer`method.

Comment: The clearFrameBuffer is a public method and will be called from the outside (I can confirm, it's called). What I would like to do is simply render a black screen. (In my code glClearColor is set to red for testing.

Comment: Do you call your function directly after `drawSample`? Would be good if you would also show this code.

Comment: No, it simply calls `[view clearFrameBuffer]`.

Comment: If you call `clearFrameBuffer` before `drawSample`, then the second method will override everything you did before. (Since it also clears the framebuffer)

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. I've added a `[self clearFrameBuffer]; return` to the top of the `drawSample:` method to be sure nothing gets overridden. However I still don't see any red on the screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90403/discussion-between-lord-zsolt-and-bdl).